# error when trying to install go oracle driver(go get gopkg.in/goracle.v2)

Tags: oracle, go

When i executed this command (go get gopkg.in/goracle.v2) in windows command prompt, got this error.

````
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:52:17: could not determine kind of name for C.dpiConn
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:347:49: could not determine kind of name for C.dpiData
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:342:20: could not determine kind of name for C.dpiNativeTypeNum
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:341:21: could not determine kind of name for C.dpiObjectType
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:343:20: could not determine kind of name for C.dpiOracleTypeNum
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:747:19: could not determine kind of name for C.dpiShutdownMode
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:724:18: could not determine kind of name for C.dpiStartupMode
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:303:15: could not determine kind of name for C.dpiStmt
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:347:37: could not determine kind of name for C.dpiVar
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:395:9: could not determine kind of name for C.dpiVersionInfo
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:351:13: could not determine kind of name for C.int
..\..\go\src\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\conn.go:304:47: could not determine kind of name for C.uint32_t```
````

Answer (score 1):

The package is archived and it's advised to use the `github.com/godror/godror` [[Reference](https://github.com/go-goracle/goracle/blob/master/README)]

To change everything using `sed` command, but as you're using Windows please do an equivalent thing:

Commands (using `sed`)

```
sed -i -e 's,goracle "gopkg.in/goracle.v2",godror "github.com/godror/godror",g; s,gopkg.in/goracle.v2,github.com/godror/godror,g; s/"goracle"/"godror"/g; s/goracle[.]/godror./g' $(find . -type f -name '*.go')

sed -i -e '/goracle.v2/d' go.mod
```

But in simpler terms I'd say as `gopkg.in/goracle.v2` is now archived, try `go get github.com/godror/godror`.

Comment: @raghul If the answer helped you in solving your issue, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the error isn't resolved yet. Im getting the same error when i used "go get github.com/godror/godror"